# Convert array to JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an array:

```
["dyGYrcK", "tRCCMsK" ,"CM1HGi3"]
```

I want to convert it to json like this:

```
{
    data: [
      {
        "expiry" : 0,
        "tokens" : {
            "0" : "dyGYrcK",
            "1" : "tRCCMsK",
            "2" : "CM1HGi3"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I am finding this to be very difficult. I have tried alot and I am getting this output currently:

```
{
  "data": [
    "dyGYrcK",
    "tRCCMsK",
    "CM1HGi3"
  ]
}
```

I am currently doing this:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data], 201); //$data is array
```

Comment: can't you just roll up your own, you already know what `$data` is

Answer (score 3):

The data array needs the keys **expiry** and **tokens**.
If you want JSON encode to set the key's you have to set them also.

**So I think your array must look like:**

```
$data = [
    "expiry" => 0, 
    "tokens" => [
        "0" => "dyGYrcK",
        "1" => "tRCCMsK",
        "2" => "CM1HGi3"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the numeric index you want inside the `token` structure, you need to convert your array to an object first. Then you simply add the properties to a new, "blank" object ... and finally you encode that object as JSON.

```
$array = ["dyGYrcK", "tRCCMsK" ,"CM1HGi3"];

$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->data[] = ['expiry' => 0, 'tokens' => (object) $array];
echo json_encode($obj);

// output:
// {"data":[{"expiry":0,"tokens":{"0":"dyGYrcK","1":"tRCCMsK","2":"CM1HGi3"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tokens = ["dyGYrcK", "tRCCMsK" ,"CM1HGi3"] ;

$data = [
    'expiry' => 0,
    'tokens' => (object)$tokens
];

return response()->json(['data' => [$data]], 201);
```

Results in

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "expiry": 0,
            "tokens": {
                "0": "dyGYrcK",
                "1": "tRCCMsK",
                "2": "CM1HGi3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```